# how to make only one part of Flex column's text centered, and other part left-aligned?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make it so that "About Lorem" is centered while the rest of the text is left-aligned.

How might this be achieved?
I tried wrapping "About Lorem" in a span and giving it a different text-align property but it didn't react to this change so I reverted the code.
Thank you for any assistance.

```css
 .container{
    width:75%;
    }
    
    .boxOuter{
        padding:45px;
        background:black;
    }
    
    .box{
      display: flex;
      width: 75%;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 500px;
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background: lightblue;    
        align-items:center;
        
         
        
    }
    .left-col {
      flex-basis: 10%;
      /*background: lightblue;*/
    align-self:center;
        
        
    }
    
    .right-col {
      background: green;
        text-align:center;
        
    }
```

```html
     <section class="section-about">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="boxOuter">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="left-col"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/pokejungle.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Pikachu.gif?resize=653%2C724&ssl=1" width="200px"></div>
                        <div class="right-col">
                            
                                <strong>About Lorem</strong>
                                <br>
                                lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
                                <br>
                                lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
                                <br>
                                lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a problem here. `<span>`s do not accept text-align, because it's inline. You can use a `<p>` with a class instead, make it bold and remove its margins. Let me show you how:
You will need to change your `<span>` to a `<p>` and add a class to it:

```
<p class="about">About Lorem</p>
```

Then you will need to make it bold (strong) and remove its margins, as it adds some...

```
.about{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Result:

[image: result 1, looks a bit wrong...]

Hmmm... That looks a bit wrong. So we could add a padding-top to make it have some distance and not touch the parent's top.

```
.about{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Full code:

```
        <section class="section-about">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="boxOuter">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="left-col"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/pokejungle.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Pikachu.gif?resize=653%2C724&ssl=1" width="200px"></div>
                        <div class="right-col">
                            
                                <p class="about">About Lorem</p>
                                <br>
                                lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
                                <br>
                                lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
                                <br>
                                lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <style>
            .about{
                text-align:center;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-top:0px;
                margin-bottom:0px;
                padding-top: 15px;
            }

            .container{
                width:75%;
            }

            .boxOuter{
                padding:45px;
                background:black;
            }

            .box{
              display: flex;
              width: 75%;
              height: 500px;
              position: relative;
              margin: 0 auto;
              height: 500px;
              /*overflow: hidden;*/
            background: lightblue;    
                align-items:center;



            }
            .left-col {
              flex-basis: 10%;
              /*background: lightblue;*/
            align-self:center;


            }

            .right-col {
                background: green;
                text-align:left;

            }
        </style>
```

(A snippet looked really bad because it was small so I didn't add one).

Also, the question isn't about flexbox, as the right-col is not a flex box.